# How to deploy properly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make a software that will execute .exe installation files of some other software using c# vs2013. I have used

```
Process.Start()
```

I added the files to be extracted in my resources and then I gave the resources path of those files

```
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Farjad\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\RoyalComputerProject\\RoyalComputerProject\\Resources\\wrar501.exe");
```

It works fine on my computer However if I try to run it on some other computer it gives me an error saying that specified files are missing. I think It is because of the path I am passing to Process.Start() is of my computer. How should I correct this? What path should I pass? or How should I deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ship your app along with dlls and this exe file in a package so when you extract it on another computer, you will get something like

```
C:/.../Downloads/YourAppName/
  - MyApp.exe
  - SomeLibrary.dll
  - Config.xml
  - MyOtherApp.exe
```

And now, you need to get a correct path of the running assembly which you could do using

```
string path;
path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

I found this code on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx).

For testing purposes, put that exe in `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` folder, depending on how you build your app (debug vs release mode).